# Kotlin coroutine execution order

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to understand kotlin coroutine.

For this code,

```
fun main() = runBlocking {
  launch {
    println("World!")
  }
  println("Hello")
}
```

is it guaranteed that "Hello" is always be printed before "World!"? I know that both println statements will be run on main thread, so my understanding is that their order is guaranteed. I just wanted to confirm it.

Comment: I believe the execution order isn't guaranteed in this case. While "Hello World!" order is a pretty reliable assumption, it is better to set the order explicitly. You should also consider such case, that in he future you change the dispatcher and forget that your code assumed ordering, so it is no longer correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not guaranteed.  It can run in either order.

Comment: I tried this code:
fun main() = runBlocking {
    launch {
        println("World!, " + Thread.currentThread().id + ", "  + Thread.currentThread().name)
    }
    println("Hello, " + Thread.currentThread().id + ", "  + Thread.currentThread().name)
}
The output is:
Hello, 1, main @coroutine#1
World!, 1, main @coroutine#2

It seems like the two statements ran on main thread.

Comment: Well, actually they are guaranteed to run on the main thread. `runBlocking()` without specified dispatcher creates a single-threaded dispatcher, using the thread that invoked `runBlocking()`

Comment: Huh.  Good to know, but the execution order still isn't guaranteed.

Comment: One more question. 'println("Hello")' is not a suspending function. Why isn't the order of the two println statements not guaranteed? What kind of target code will kotlin compile the code in my question to so the execution order of the two println statements is not guaranteed?

Comment: What would you expect to happen in `runBlocking { launch { println("World!") } Thread.sleep(1000); println("Hello") }`?  No suspend functions in there.

Comment: `runBlocking { launch { println("World!") } Thread.sleep(1000); println("Hello") }` still generated 'Hello\nWorld!'. Only `runBlocking { launch { println("World!") } delay(1000); println("Hello") }` generated 'World!\nHello', but 'delay' is a suspend function.